# Cannot build C project with cmake when using stb_image library on MacOS

Tags: c, cmake, stb-image

When I try to build my project using this cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(C_Projects C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/stb_image)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}_DIR}/stb_image)

add_library(stb_image stb_image/stb_image.h)
add_library(stb_image_write stb_image/stb_image_write.h)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(stb_image PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(stb_image_write PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

add_executable(C_Projects main.c)

target_link_libraries(C_Projects stb_image stb_image_write)
```

I get the cmake error of:

```
ar: ar: no archive members specifiedno archive members specified

usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[3]: make[3]: *** [libstb_image.a] Error 1*** [libstb_image_write.a] Error 1

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stb_image.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stb_image_write.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/C_Projects.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [C_Projects] Error 2
```

Here is where I include the library in my source file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image/stb_image.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image/stb_image_write.h"
```

I have looked at all the related questions on stack overflow about installing stb_image with cmake and none of those solutions have worked for me. What am I doing wrong ?

I have compiled my code with GCC and it works fine, but now I need to use the debugger of my IDE and for this I have to compile it with cmake.

Comment: Please provide the complete output of `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: The error is not specific to stb-image. You are trying to create a library from just headers (without sources) and this is wrong. The library without source files is known as header-only library, and CMake provides special kind of target for it: INTERFACE. See duplicate questions for more info.